# How to parse inner class from java source code

Tags: java, javaparser

I use the https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser to parse the java source code

I tried a lot of methods to parse inner class ; like this :

```
class A {
    int x;
    public void method2() {...}
        class B {
            int number;
            public void methods() {...}
        }
    }
```

I try to parse class B and it's variables and methods, but I failed.

Is there any example to show how to get the B class?

I can parse class A methods name and content or variables content, like this:

```
 CompilationUnit cu = JavaParser.parse(in);

 ClassVisitor classVisitor = new ClassVisitor();
 classVisitor.visit(cu, null);

 class ClassVisitor extends VoidVisitorAdapter<Void> {
    @Override
    public void visit(ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration n, Void arg) {
        System.out.println(n.getFields());

        // get class methods
        for(MethodDeclaration method : n.getMethods()) {
            System.out.println("Name :" + method.getName());
            System.out.println("Body :" + method.getBody().get());
           }
        }
    }
}
```

But I try to parse class B varible and method ,failed!

try the CompilationUnit.getTypes(), like this :

```
CompilationUnit cu = JavaParser.parse(in);

for(TypeDeclaration<?> type : cu.getTypes()) {
    log.info("Type Name :{}", type.getName());
}
```

result :
n.s.dictionary.parse.JavaCodeParse       : Type Name :A

Not resolved to B class

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full source code you have and describe how it fails (error message, wrong value, ...). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: But I want to analyze the unknown java file, so I don't know what class it contains.

Comment: I think maybe the CompilationUnit.getTypes() call might return the names of any nested classes (but I'm not familiar with it so just guessing).

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I tried it but it didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For somebody who need it :

```
for(TypeDeclaration type : cu.getTypes()) {
        // first give all this java doc member
        List<BodyDeclaration> members = type.getMembers();
        // check all member content
        for(BodyDeclaration member : members) {
            // if member state equal ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration, and you can identify it which is inner class
            if(member.isClassOrInterfaceDeclaration()) {
                log.info("class name :{}", member.asClassOrInterfaceDeclaration().getName());
                // get inner class method
                for(MethodDeclaration method : member.asClassOrInterfaceDeclaration().getMethods()) {
                    log.info("Method Name :{}", method.getName());
                }
                VerifyInnerClassAndParse(member.asClassOrInterfaceDeclaration());
            }
        }
    }
```

if you hava many inner class, just write recursive method

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for recursivity you just have to invoke super.visit(n, arg) in your visitor method.